# Handling Invalid Character Constant

Tags: java

I have been working on a data compression and decompression program in java. At some point in my code, I want to visit only the nodes with keys. The part of the code looks like this:

```
//visit only nodes with keys
if(n.alpha != '&#092;&#048;') {
     System.out.println("{" + n.alpha + ":" + s + "}");
     charToCode.put(n.alpha, s);
     codeToChar.put(s, n.alpha);
}
```

'\0' gives me an invalid character constant. I need to know what is going on, and how I can remedy the situation. Thanks!

Comment: single quotes in java will be used for char. `&#092;&#048;` is a string.

Comment: can you try "&#092;&#048;" instead of '&#092;&#048;'

Comment: Thanks Partha. But, alpha is a character. I have tried using double quotes, but all to no avail.

Comment: What type is `n.alpha`? Is it a `char`? If so, you must compare it with a char, but `'&#092;&#048;'` is an _invalid character constant_, because it is more of a string. If `n.alpha` is a string, then simply compare it with `n.alpha.equals("&#092;&#048;")`. Additionally, you mentioned the error that "'\0' gives me an invalid character constant", but your code does not show any '\0' constant.

Comment: Hello, n is a node, and alpha is a character. I am using this for my data compression and decompression program.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do - to what character do you want to compare `n.alpha`? `&#092;&#048;` is obviously not a valid character.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to represent and treat a String as a char

```
n.alpha != '&#092;&#048;' // single quotes denote a character
```

You need to use a String instead

```
n.alpha != "&#092;&#048;"
```

Then, because the equality operator generally shouldn't be used with Strings, and because you're incorrectly testing the equality between a `String` and a `char`, you need to rewrite it as

```
if(!Character.toString(n.alpha).equals("&#092;&#048;"))
```

Note the use of `Character.toString(n.alpha)` to convert the char `n.alpha` to a String.

Comment: Hey Steve, do you think that would work? n is a node, alpha is a character. I need to make this work for my compression program to be completed.

Comment: @James It's semantically identical to what you wrote in your original question.  It doesn't matter that `n` is a node (which I'm guessing is a class you wrote), because you're using `n.alpha` - and that's a `char`.  Convert the `char` to a `String` and now everything you're working with for this test is of the same object type.

Comment: Remember to give feedback if it solves your problem.